# Can’t open chromium or Firefox on RPi Zero W

Tags: raspbian, google-chrome, firefox

I’ve got a new RPi zero W and I’ve install raspbian using the imager tool (32 bit) and when booted the OS works fine, all programs open etc except for web browsers.

I’ve reinstalled chrome and even installed Firefox, but none will open up, it just shows the timer curser (like it’s doing something) and then nothing.

Also, installed all updates and reinstalled the OS, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you mean chromium, not chrome, the distinction is not meaningless. Anyway, try opening it from the command line in a terminal -- sometimes there may be a bit of output that sheds some light. The command may block, which is good. If it does not (ie., the command line comes back, but the timer cursor is still going), don't do anything in that terminal because output may still go there. For firefox, the command is just `firefox`, dunno what it is for chromium.   You should also check on the process in another terminal, try `top -p $(pidof firefox)`.

Comment: it's a Zero W (just updated post)

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this while trying to find an answer as to why I couldn't install Firefox (short answer, it seems like they removed the arm6 compatible versions from every legitimate link I could find).

Make sure you're using Buster 32 bit. I just set up my Pi Zero W from scratch, the only thing I did was install it to the SD card, run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and then run:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

In action:[image: Chromium on Raspberry Pi W Zero]

You can also install Midori instead of Chrome/Firefox if you are having issues with them.

Use:

```
sudo apt-get install midori
```